# Twitter Error App Inventor 2

Tags: twitter-oauth, app-inventor

I'm having an issue when trying to Call Twitter.Authorize in App Inventor 2. I have the correct consumer key and secret set when the screen initialized but I'm getting the following error within he emulator.

[image: Emulator Error]

Also here is a screen grab of the consumer key/secret being initialized.

[image: Block Editor]

I can't figure it out at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be, you did not follow exactly the steps to get a consumer key and consumer secret. Especially make sure, you defined a **callback url** (this can be any url).

[see also this tutorial](https://puravidaapps.com/twitter.php)

[image]